# Laravel 5.1: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel-5.1

When i make a request from a form in Laravel in order to store it in a database, it throws this error: **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.

I cannot understand what i have done wrong so can you please help me?

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/ajax/edit">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="textEdit">
            <div class="marginizer"> 
                <textarea id="edit" name="edit"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'Dashboard@index');
Route::get('admin/dashboard/{id}', 'Dashboard@show');
Route::get('admin/dashboard/edit/{site}', 'Edit@edit');
Route::get('admin', 'Dashboard@index');

// Register and Login routes...
Route::get('admin/login', 'Login@index');
Route::get('admin/register', 'Register@index');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

// Ajax routes
Route::post('admin/ajax/edit', 'EditAjax@store');

// UI routes
Route::get('/', 'ThemeLoader@index');
Route::get('/{site}', 'ThemeLoader@show');

Route::get('migrate', 'migrate@migrate');
Route::get('migrate/refresh', 'migrate@refresh');
```

And here is my controller which handles the request:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $content = new Content;

    $content->site = 'Index';
    $content->block = 1;
    $content->content = $request->input('edit');
    $content->active = 1;

    $content->save();
}
```

It actually stores the data in the database correctly but it continues to come up with an error.

Comment: maybe your route is not correct? try switching your action to `action="{{ url('admin/ajax/edit') }}"

Comment: can you post your ajax call

Comment: I'm not using ajax, i was previusly but not anymore

Comment: if that is the case then you will need to add a `return` in your `store` method.. and it would probably make sense to not call it `ajax` anymore

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you check your route via `php artisan route:list` ?
Sometimes when i fiddle with route, i got MethodNotAllowedHttpException and had to clear it's cache.

**Edit** as kofi pointed. it is possible if you had your laravel project directory not direct child of htdocs. So, it is better to try `{{ route('admin/ajax/edit') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin/ajax/edit') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

**MethodNotAllowedHttpException** 
Usually happens when you try to use an HTTP method for a route but you have not defined that method in your routes file. For example, if you POST to a method, but you only define a GET method for the route in routes.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i guess it may help you:

```
<?php 
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'YourController@YourAction', 'method' => 'post')) }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        "..Your Form Inputs.."
    {{ Form::close() }}
?>
```